# How to design textfield like "To" field in email with autocompletes

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, uitextview

I have a requirement to create text field similar to "To" in email where once I enter email id it locks in a control(assuming button)  and provides feasibility to add another email id

Also once the label is locked, on tap of backspace to remove entire email block of button

How can i achieve this

Any ideas please[image]

Comment: In iOS 13 use `UISearchTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try layout like this:

```
UILabel - UIStackView (horizontal) - UITextField
```

And when UITextField did end editing, you just add your custom view (which is an email button) to your UIStackView

Answer (score 0):

First make `UILabel` of Text "To" then place a Horizontal Stack View to right of this `UILabel`. And then place `UITextField`. `UITextField` leading constraint will be `Horizontal StackView` Trailing. Initially `StackView` will be empty so it does not take any width and your `UITextField` will be place at your horizontal stackView.